# sending email only works after connecting with telnet first

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I am trying to send emails from my dotnet 4.5 client and I have a strange problem.

the code I use is this :

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("me@here.com", "you@here.com", "blah blah blah", "whatever");

SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("relay.skynet.be", 25);
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
SmtpServer.Send(message);
```

This returns no error but no email is being send.

Now, when I open a command prompt and do this:

```
telnet  relay.skynet.be 25
```

from now on it works, and all the emails I tried to send before also arrive.

So my question is, why do I have to open a telnet session first before my dotnet client is able to send email ?
And what can I do to make it work without this ?

Comment: if SmtpClient.Send does not throw an SmtpException exception, it means that the mail message is succesfully sent to the SMTP Server. The issue may be relative to your SMTP Server. (Blacklist, ????)

Comment: ok, but how come that it suddenly works after I simply open and close a telnet to the smtp server ?

Comment: @GuidoG ask them? Anyway, if you want to see what actually goes on, use Fiddler or Wireshark to see what is sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure here, but as far as I understand, Look like telnet client not running on your system. But after running the telnet command it seems telnet started on your system and your system start communicating with telnet server.

Please correct me if i am wrong here.

Comment: why would i need to communicate with a telnet server ?